# RestructuredText: Enumerated sub-list doesn't not change value

Tags: restructuredtext

When I try to create a enumerated sub-list in HTML using RestructuredText, the sub-list does not change value in HTML, according to how I wrote it in RST. Below is an example of what I mean.

Here is how I wrote an enumerated list and sub-list in RestructuredText:

```
1. Step 1

   a. Step a
   
   b. step b

2. Step 2
```

Here is the result in HTML:

[image]

Any idea on how to resolve this?

Comment: It works as expected here with your example and `rst2html5`. You may be missing the CSS rule `ol.loweralpha { list-style: lower-alpha }` that is in the required (and provided) stylefile "minimal.css".

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately that's by design because you use the same format (`x.` where x is either a number or a letter).

The correct way to create nested is to use different format, such as

```
1. Item 1 initial text.

   a) Item 1a.
   b) Item 1b.
```

https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#enumerated-lists